# checking a single checkbox per html row using angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox

i have a table that loads multiple checkboxes and selectboxes.when i click on one checkbox or select box it automatically selects every other box on the table .i want to have the option to choose either one checkbox or select box per row on it own.

```
  <tr id="TableBody" ng-repeat="code in Register.RegisterDetails">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td   ng-bind="code .CodeID"><input type="text" ng-model="Register.CodeID" /></td>
            <td   ng-bind="code .name"><input type="text" ng-model="Register.Firstname" /></td>
            <td   ng-bind="code .Lastname"><input type="text" ng-model="Register.Lastname" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="Register.Presentstatus" id="PresentCheckbox" name="PresentCheckbox" /></td>
            <td><select id="reasons" name="reasons" ng-model="Register.Category" ng-disabled="Register.Presentstatus" ng-clicked="Register.Presentstatus && O" ></td>

        </tr>
```

my module that gets my data

```
function Register(){ self.RegisterDetails = function () {
    var params = { pass params here };
    return $http.get
        {
            url: GetRegisterDetails,
            params: params,
            success: function (data) {

                self.RegisterDetails = data.data;

            }
        });
}
```

my controller

```
ngAppModule.controller('RegisterController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http)
{
    var self = this;
   $scope.Register = new Register($http);

}]);
```

all the above code works fine. i just dont know how to check a single box per row.sorry im new to this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you're running into is you are binding to the wrong this inside your ng-repeat.

Your HTML currently repeats a checkbox for every `code`, but binds that to the *same* object property `Register.Presentstatus`.

```
  <tr id="TableBody" ng-repeat="code in Register.RegisterDetails">
       <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
       ....
       <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="Register.Presentstatus" .../></td>
  </tr>
```

You'll need to bind this to a row-specific (`code`-specific) property if you want each row to have independent check boxes.  Perhaps you are looking for something that binds the checkbox to an element in an array:

```
  <tr id="TableBody" ng-repeat="code in Register.RegisterDetails">
       <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
       ....
       <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="Register.Presentstatus[$index]" .../></td>
  </tr>
```

or actually binds to a property of the `code` object

```
  <tr id="TableBody" ng-repeat="code in Register.RegisterDetails">
       <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
       ....
       <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="code.Presentstatus" .../></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: hi thank you so much, i tried it with the [$index] first and it didnt work,it wasnt allowing me to select anything. so i tried your second option and that works perfect.

Comment: The first approach doesn't work correctly when in future you to need a filter... Use the second approach, with code object.

Answer (score 0):

Since youur ng-model="Register.Presentstatus" is repeating and is same for all so you have same binding for all rows. you can alter them to have different binding